# Android - Rewarded video ads never load again after the app is closed

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I am new to Android rewarded video ads. I tried to create an application with rewarded video ads as is explained in [Rewarded Ads: Publishers Get Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/rewarded-video)

There is a button, in the application, that allows the user to view a rewarded video. The button is enabled after the video is loaded.

The first time I open the application everything works. I can view several video ads by pressing the button. The problem is, after I close the application, by pressing the back button, and open it again. Then, the ads never load again. I receive no messages from the RewardedVideoAdListener and I put a Toast in very function. There simply is no feedback. I should be able to view a Toast in the onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad, but not even that happens. It is as if the code completely fails to execute.

As I said, I am new to Android rewarded video ads. Perhaps I am doing something wrong but I can't figure out what. I have already searched the Internet, but I can't find any answer. Some people mention problems when loading ads, but not the specific problem of ads not loading after the application is closed and opened again. I also checked this question but nobody answered:
[Question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962662/android-reward-video-ads-not-loading-after-loading-once)

I ran the app in different phones and I always find this problem.

Can anyone help me?

Sorry for my English. I am not a native speaker.

Here is the code in my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {

    private Button mWatchButton;
    private TextView mRewardLabel;
    private RewardedVideoAd mAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mWatchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_watch);

        mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        loadAd();

        mWatchButton.setEnabled(false);
        mWatchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mAd.isLoaded()){
                        mAd.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadAd(){
        if(!mAd.isLoaded()){
            mAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        mWatchButton.setEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mWatchButton.setEnabled(false);
        loadAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mRewardLabel.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "You got %d %s!", rewardItem.getAmount(), rewardItem.getType()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mAd.pause(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAd.resume(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mAd.destroy(this);
    }


}
```

Here is the code from my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.xxxxxx.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ver o anúncio"
        android:id="@+id/btn_watch"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I receive no warning or error messages in logcat in Android Studio.

I am using:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

and

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app enters the foreground again request another ad:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadAd();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was a real life saver! Still, I had to do a little more modifications to get it to work. It seems the !mAd.isLoaded() in the loadAd() function was always returning true, so the ad was never re-initialized. Strange... So my new loadAd() function is:     
private void loadAd(){
        //if(!mAd.isLoaded()){
            mAd = null;       
            mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
            mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
            mAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        //}
    }